# Prove: if $\text{rank}(A)=\text{rank}(A^2)$ then $Ax=0$ and $A^2x=0$ have the same set of solutions.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Let $A\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb F)$. Prove that if $\text{rank}(A)=\text{rank}(A^2)$ then the systems $Ax=0$ and $A^2x=0$ have the same set of solutions.

I don't really have a clue where to start with this one. Multiplying the matrices didn't seem to help much. The only case that I could solve is if $A$ is an invertible matrix because $Ax=0\Leftrightarrow A^{-1}Ax=A^{-1}0\Leftrightarrow x=0$, similarly for $A^2x=0$.

Comment: Hint: what can you say about the dimension of the kernels? can you say that one of the kernels is contained in the other?

Comment: Take a look at [Relationship between nullspaces of A when $rank(A) = rank(A^2)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3896178/relationship-between-nullspaces-of-a-when-ranka-ranka2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$n-\dim(\ker A^2)=\text{rank}~ A^2=\text{rank}~ A=n-\dim(\ker A)$$

we get

$$\dim(\ker A^2)=\dim(\ker A)\tag{1}$$

We also know:

$$x\in\ker A\Rightarrow Ax=0\Rightarrow A^2x=0\Rightarrow x\in \ker A^2$$
hence

$$\ker A\subseteq \ker A^2\tag{2}$$

By (1) and (2), what can you conclude?

Answer (score 3):

Use the fact that ${\rm Ker} A \subseteq {\rm Ker} A^2$ which is true in general. (To see why, if we have $x \in {\rm Ker} A$, then $A x = 0 \implies A^2 x = A (A x) = A (0) = 0$, so that $x \in {\rm Ker} A^2$.) Combined with the fact that ${\rm rank} A = {\rm rank} A^2 \implies {\rm nul} A = {\rm nul} A^2$, this shows that ${\rm Ker} A = {\rm Ker} A^2$.

Answer (score 1):

One can easily check that $$\rm Im(A)=Im(A^2)\Longleftrightarrow Ker(A)=Ker(A^2)$$
Make use of the formula
$$\rm dim(Ker(A))+dim(Im(A))=n$$